# How to hide a View parameter from the URL in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a view which displays the objects of a model. The objects are sorted using a key which I want to have as a view parameter so that I can create a system where the user gets to pick on how to sort the query sets.
I currently have it set up as follows:

```
def comics(request, sorting_key):
    comics = Comic.objects.all().order_by(sorting_key)
    ...
```

However, the problem is that I need to include the sorting key somewhere in the url as well, and I don't want that. Is there any way to get around this problem? Or am I stuck with an URL that explicitly shows the sorting key?

Comment: How do you want to specify the key, if not in the URL?

Comment: I was thinking about only keeping it in the view. I was asking if there was a way to still make it passable through a URL, without having it mentioned in the URL. Sort of like a hidden parameter I guess.

Comment: How do users pick the sorting key?

Comment: @albar - its a dropdown menu, 3 options, each linking to the same URL with a different sorting key.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of cookies, you can set cookie on client browser when user changes the parameter of sorting and reload the page to sort the data, which will call the same view again, read the cookie from request in your view and sort on that parameter.

Do take care of default parameter when cookie is not set or sorting on that key is not available, because user can change or delete the cookie.

Comment: Rather than explicitly setting cookies, OP should really use the built-in session framework.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Can you please elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `<a>` tags in the menu links with `<form>` tags with the same URL, and send the sorting key using post, and read it from `request.POST` in the view.